# Using Instagram Basic Display API to get user's metadata

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, api, instagram

I am currently working on an iOS-App where Instagram users can fetch their data, such as profile information and images and will be able to post. There are similar apps like Flume (https://flumeapp.com/) which are capable of accessing those features. I already managed to get the access token and fetch the basic user information.

As the Instagram Legacy API will be shut down soon, I am wondering how to fetch detailed user information, as the Basic Display API only lists fields for *account type*, *id*, *username* and *media count* (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user#fields).

In both the Basic Display API as well as the Graph API it says that creating media is not supported.

Can anyone tell me how other apps (like Flume) are able to perform those actions? Are they perhaps still using the Instagram Legacy API?

Thanks!

Comment: Could still be using old APIs; could have a special partnership with Facebook that gives them access to features normal 3rd-party apps don’t get; could be reverse-engineered API calls …

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I also found "Later" and they are an Instagram partner, might explain it..